# Delegation of sub-domain

Tags: dns, delegation, nameservers

I have a domain xyz.com whose registrar and web host are different. I have pointed the registrars name server entries to the web hosts ns01.host.com, etc.

On the web host, I have now created sub.xyz.com and want to delegate this domain to an external name server. Of course this is not possible straight off since the web host only allows IP Addresses against Custom A records.

What are my options to delegate sub.xyz.com to ns01.externalnameserver.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of an A record on your registrar, you may use CNAME record to point the subdomain to an external address.